# How can I store data into a variable only once?

Tags: jquery, loops, variables, datatables

```
'createdCell':  function (cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex) {
   if(Array.isArray(cellData)){
       console.log(colIndex);
       var myfirstArray = colIndex;
   }
}
```

My console.log(colIndex) output is:

```
3 
4
```

What I want to do is store the first value (in this case `3` into the variable `myfirstArray`. Is there a way to stop the script to store other data into the variable after storing the first? Because right now `myfirstArray` is set to `3`, but after that this is overwritten by `4`?

Comment: Presumably the `createdCell` function is called multiple times. As such, if you want to deal with one or multiple of the values provided to its arguments, you will need to do it within the scope of that function.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Maybe there is a way to check if the function was called for the first time?

Comment: There is, but the `myfirstArray` variable is only in scope of that function, so the point becomes moot - unless you make the variable global, but that's not good practice and should be avoided.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well, I understand. But fact is that I have a certain amount of cells. this is fix. and the lowest number of that celldata, which is defined as array is always `3`. No matter how many time the function is called. It is always `3`

Comment: This means in each function, I need to set my variable `myfirstArray` to `3`. Do you know how I mean it? Maybe confusing

Comment: Bit confusing with `myfirstarray` inside the `isarray` - but if you put it outside with `var myfirstArray = null`, then you can use the shorthand `myfirstArray = myfirstArray || colIndex`

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) Explain your higher level use case or problem you are trying to solve in more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Both variables sohuld be global
let functionAlreadyVisited = false;
let myfirstArray;
// ...

'createdCell':  function (cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex) {
   if(!functionAlreadyVisited && Array.isArray(cellData)){
       functionAlreadyVisited = true;
       console.log(colIndex);
       myfirstArray = colIndex;
   }

   if(Array.isArray(cellData)){
       $(cell).attr('data-original-title', 'This is my first Array:'+ myfirstArray);
   }

   return myfirstArray;
}
```

Comment: This unfortunalely does not work. In every function I need to have access to myfirstArray=3

Comment: @marila Then can you explain a bit more clearly what you want to do and show how you call `createdCell`? You can update your question.

Comment: Yes, its acually almost what I need. Imagine the function is fired and myfirstArray is set to 3, then the function is fired again, but I need to get access to "3". Is it then possible to set myfirstArray to "global" or return it, so that I can get access to it, the next time the function is fired?

Comment: Thank you! I checked your code. I forgot to tell you,that in the last line inside the function I have this code:   `$(cell).attr('data-original-title', 'this is my first Array:' +myfirstArray);`

Comment: But if I use this now, then I get the error message: `unreachable code after return statement`

Comment: Update your question will all your code to see what is around `createdCell` please

Comment: Ok, one second!

Comment: Show the code where your function is called.
`return myfirstArray;` should be the last line of your function

Comment: The return statement should be at the end of your function

Comment: If I put return to the end, then the result is 'This is my first Array: undefined'

Comment: I have only access to the variable inside the if statement `if(!functionAlreadyVisited && Array.isArray(cellData)){`